# Очистка в useEffect React

Tags: reactjs, select, redux

очень прошу вашей помощи. Дело в том, что я не понимаю как правильно мне очистить state redux перед размонтированием компонента. У меня есть связные списки select, при выборе любого из них делается api запрос и меняются данные в других. Всё работает отлично до тех пор, пока я не буду переходить с одной такой страницы на другую. Т.е. у меня есть табы, на одном табе связные списки и на другом. Если я буду переключать табы то мои запросы удваиваются, так как функция очистки в useEffect не успевает очистить state, из за этого при загрузке компонента происходит первая цепочка запросов и при наблюдением за select сразу же вторая. Как мне подождать пока отработает функция очистки, перед тем как подгружать другой таб?

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchCoursesByGroup({ idPlan, idGroup })); // Получаю данные для заполнения первого списка
    
    // В reducer просто обновляю state пустым массивом
    return () => {
      dispatch(changePlan(planFields)); // Очищаю таблицу, которая была получена на основе выбранных значений из списка
      dispatch(setAllFormControl([])); // Очищаю Формы контроля
      dispatch(setSemestersCourse([])); // Очищаю курсы
      dispatch(setGroupCourses([])); // Очищаю семестры
    };
  }, []);
```

Все списки я получаю посредством того же useEffect к примеру:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (watchCourse) getSemesters(watchCourse); // Если выбран курс, получаю семестры на этот курс
  }, [watchCourse]);
```

В конце выполняется функция, где так же делается api запрос на сервер с выбранными в select значениями для получения таблицы. И вот тут происходит конфуз. Так как useEffect не успел почистить курсы, семестры, формы контроля и тд, то данные до сих пор есть и при загрузке страницы сразу же срабатывает запрос на получения таблицы, потом срабатывает следующий useEffect который при загрузке страницы получает данные для первого списка, что вызывает цепочку useEffect для получения данных последующих списков и в конце повторный запрос на таблицу...

Полный код компонента со связными списками

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchCoursesByGroup } from '../../../store/Actions/coursesAction';
import { fetchSemestersByCourse } from '../../../store/Actions/semestersAction';
import { fetchAllFormControl } from '../../../store/Actions/formControlAction';
import { fetchPlan } from '../../../store/Actions/planAction';
import { planReducer } from '../../../store/Reducers/planReducer';
import { formControlReducer } from '../../../store/Reducers/formControlReducer';
import { semestersReducer } from '../../../store/Reducers/semestersReducer';
import { coursesReducer } from '../../../store/Reducers/coursesReducer';
import { plan as planFields } from '../../../store/fields/planFields';
import Filter from '../../Basic/Filter';

function PlanFilter({ idGroup, idPlan, callbackSemester = () => {}, callbackControl = () => {} }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { register, watch, setValue } = useForm();
  const watchCourse = watch('coursesSelect');
  const watchSemester = watch('semestersSelect');
  const watchControl = watch('controlsSelect');
  const coursesSelect = register('coursesSelect');
  const semestersSelect = register('semestersSelect');
  const controlsSelect = register('controlsSelect');

  const courses = useSelector((state) => state.coursesReducer.groupCourses);
  const semesters = useSelector((state) => state.semestersReducer.semestersCourse);
  const formControl = useSelector((state) => state.formControlReducer.all);

  const { changePlan } = planReducer.actions;
  const { setAllFormControl } = formControlReducer.actions;
  const { setSemestersCourse } = semestersReducer.actions;
  const { setGroupCourses } = coursesReducer.actions;
  
  // Получаю курсы в первый select и очищаю при размонтировании компонента
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchCoursesByGroup({ idPlan, idGroup }));

    return () => {
      dispatch(changePlan(planFields));
      dispatch(setAllFormControl([]));
      dispatch(setSemestersCourse([]));
      dispatch(setGroupCourses([]));
    };
  }, []);
  
  // Здесь я хочу чтоб при первой загрузке компонента установился первый элемент из массива как выбранный курс, чтоб воспроизвести цепочку и заполнить все списки сразу при загрузке страницы
  useEffect(() => {
    if (courses.length > 0 && !watchCourse)
      setValue('coursesSelect', courses[0].idCoursePlan.toString());
  }, [courses]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (semesters.length > 0) setValue('semestersSelect', semesters[0].name.split(' ')[1]);
  }, [semesters]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (formControl.length > 0) {
      setValue('controlsSelect', formControl[0].id.toString());
      getPlan(); // Вызов финальной таблицы
    }
  }, [formControl]);
  
  // При изменении семестра вызываю функцию для получения через api форм контроля на выбранный семестр
  useEffect(() => {
    if (watchSemester) {
      getFormControl();
      callbackSemester(watchSemester); // Просто возвращаю выбранный семестр в родителя для других целей
    }
  }, [watchSemester]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (watchCourse) getSemesters(watchCourse);
  }, [watchCourse]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (watchControl) {
      getPlan();
      callbackControl(watchControl);
    }
  }, [watchControl]);

  const getSemesters = (idCoursePlan) =>
    dispatch(fetchSemestersByCourse({ idCoursePlan, idGroup, withActive: true }));

  const getFormControl = () => dispatch(fetchAllFormControl({ withAll: false }));

  const getPlan = () => {
    if (watchSemester && watchControl && idPlan)
      dispatch(fetchPlan({ semester: watchSemester, idControl: watchControl, idPlan }));
  };

  return (
    <Filter.Form classes={['FilterForm FilterForm_position_sticky  pb-4']}>
      <Filter.Group labelTitle="Курс:">
        <Filter.Select registered={coursesSelect}>
          {courses.map((course) => (
            <Filter.Option key={course.idCoursePlan} value={course.idCoursePlan}>
              {course.name}
            </Filter.Option>
          ))}
        </Filter.Select>
      </Filter.Group>
      <Filter.Group labelTitle="Семестр:" classes={['ml-4']}>
        <Filter.Select registered={semestersSelect}>
          {semesters.map((semester) => (
            <Filter.Option key={semester.id} value={semester.name.split(' ')[1]}>
              {semester.name}
            </Filter.Option>
          ))}
        </Filter.Select>
      </Filter.Group>
      <Filter.Group labelTitle="Форма контроля:" classes={['ml-4']}>
        <Filter.Select registered={controlsSelect}>
          {formControl.map((control) => (
            <Filter.Option key={control.id} value={control.id}>
              {control.name}
            </Filter.Option>
          ))}
        </Filter.Select>
      </Filter.Group>
    </Filter.Form>
  );
}

export default PlanFilter;
```

Код одного из reducer (курсы)

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { fetchCoursesByFacultyLevelForm, fetchCoursesByGroup } from '../Actions/coursesAction';

const initialState = {
  groupCourses: [], // вот этот массив используется для select'a
  facultyLevelForm: [],
  isLoading: false,
  error: '',
};

const pendingReducer = (state) => {
  state.isLoading = true;
};

const rejectedReducer = (state, action) => {
  state.isLoading = false;
  if (action) state.error = action.payload.error;
};

const defaultFulfilledReducer = (state) => {
  rejectedReducer(state);
};

export const coursesReducer = createSlice({
  name: 'courses',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setGroupCourses(state, action) {
      // Сюда я передаю пустой массив при 
      // размонтировании компонента, это я и называю очищением
      state.groupCourses = action.payload;
    },
    changeFacultyLevelForm(state, action) {
      state.facultyLevelForm = action.payload;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [fetchCoursesByGroup.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.groupCourses = action.payload;
      defaultFulfilledReducer(state); // Заполняю курсы с api
    },
    [fetchCoursesByGroup.pending]: pendingReducer,
    [fetchCoursesByGroup.rejected]: rejectedReducer,
    [fetchCoursesByFacultyLevelForm.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.facultyLevelForm = action.payload;
      defaultFulfilledReducer(state);
    },
    [fetchCoursesByFacultyLevelForm.pending]: pendingReducer,
    [fetchCoursesByFacultyLevelForm.rejected]: rejectedReducer,
  },
});

export default coursesReducer.reducer;
```

Все остальные редюсеры выполнены абсолютно таким же образом.

Код главной страницы куда монтируются все табы.

```
<BaseLayout
      callbackSelectedGroup={(e) => setSelectedGroup(e)}
      tabs={selectedGroup ? ['Контингент', 'Учебный план', 'Успеваемость'] : []}
      callbackSelectedTab={(e) => setTab(e)}
    >
      {tab === 1 && <Contingent idGroup={group.id} />}
      {tab === 2 && <Plan idGroup={group.id} />}
      {tab === 3 && <Progress idGroup={group.id} />}
    </BaseLayout>
```

Код таба Plan (Учебный план)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import withReactContent from 'sweetalert2-react-content';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
import { PencilAltIcon } from '@heroicons/react/outline';
import FileDropper from '../../FileDropper';
import {
  fetchPlan,
  fetchPlanIdByGroup,
  savePlan as savePlanAction,
  uploadPlan as uploadFileDispatch,
} from '../../../store/Actions/planAction';
import HeaderPlan from './HeaderPlan';
import BodyPlan from './BodyPlan';
import PlanFilter from './PlanFilter';
import { ContextItem, ContextList, ContextMenu } from '../../ContextMenu';
import { ReactComponent as NotFoundSvg } from '../../../images/undraw_not_found.svg';
import MTable from '../../Tables/MainTable';

function Plan() {
  const TheSwal = withReactContent(Swal);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  // Store
  const idPlan = useSelector((store) => store.planReducer.idPlan);
  const plan = useSelector((store) => store.planReducer.plan);
  const group = useSelector((store) => store.groupsReducer.selectedGroup);
  // State
  const [editMode, setEditMode] = useState(false);
  const [selectedSemester, setSelectedSemester] = useState();
  const [selectedControl, setSelectedControl] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (group)
      dispatch(
        fetchPlanIdByGroup({
          idSpecialty: group.spesialty_id,
          yearAdmission: group.group_date_start,
        }),
      );
  }, [group]);

  return (
    <div className="Main__ContentContainer">
      {idPlan.id && (
        {/* Это компонент со связными списками, код которого я предоставил выше*/}
        <PlanFilter
          idPlan={idPlan.id}
          idGroup={group.id}
          callbackSemester={(e) => setSelectedSemester(e)}
          callbackControl={(e) => setSelectedControl(e)}
        />
      )}
      {idPlan.id && (
        <>
          <MTable.Table>
            <HeaderPlan
              editMode={editMode}
              callbackCancelEdit={cancelEdit}
              callbackSaveEdit={savePlan}
            />
            <BodyPlan
              editMode={editMode}
              callbackCancelEdit={cancelEdit}
              callbackSaveEdit={savePlan}
            />
          </MTable.Table>
        </>
      )}
export default Plan;
```

Воспроизведение ситуации:

1. Грузится первый таб (Контингент см скрин 1 или 2)
2. Перехожу на второй там (Учебный план) выполняется необходимое кол-во запросов (4 запроса: Получение курсов, семестров, форм контроля и финальной таблицы)
3. Перехожу на тертий таб (Успеваемость), где структура точно такая же как и на втором табе, те же связные списки. Тут уже происходит вакханалия, запросы дублируются, цепь useEffect выполняется дважды, так как с прошлого таба данные не успели почиститься.
4. Возвращаюсь на второй таб и запросы снова дублируются, так как теперь третий там не успел почистить за собой.
   Если я буду переключатся между первым и вторым табом - всё будет отлично, так как на первом нет связных списков и он не вызывает запросы на курсы и прочее, поэтому между этими двумя всё будет хорошо, а между табами которые заполняют связные списки используя одни и те же запросы, одни и теже state из стора, происходит вот такой вот казус.

[image: Первый таб со связными списками]
[image: Второй таб со связными списками]
[image: Дублирующие запросы при переходе между табами]

Comment: Подозреваю что у вас страница не размонтируется, поэтому и `useEffect` не очищаетс. Вы уверены, что функции внутри `return` в `useEffect` вызываются?

Comment: Я ставил consol.log в функцию внутри return и он срабатывал перед переходом на другой таб

Comment: Хорошо, второй вопрос. Что означает очищаю запросы? Или вы имеете в виду данные которые внутри select-a? У вас в редаксе вы в одном месте храните все данные для нескольких страниц? Типа country и для первой страницы и для второй.

Comment: Я отредактировал вопрос, добавив в него код одного из моих редьюсеров. По сути  да, я получаю курсы допустим и стучусь к ним на разных страницах.

Comment: Я думаю что ошибка в том, что я не могу сделать к примеру await на этот dispatch, чтобы подождать пока значение в сторе обновится, а уже после размонтировать компонент. Я хотел бы сразу извинится если моё предположение глупое, я не так давно занимаюсь реактом. Просто как же мне подождать пока значение не будет изменено?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем я придумал решение, не знаю насколько оно правильное, но я просто отказался от использования store в данном случае. В итоге теперь всё выглядит примерно так:

```
useEffect(() => {
    resetField('coursesSelect');
    resetField('semestersSelect');
    resetField('controlsSelect');

    (async () => {
      const { payload } = await dispatch(fetchCoursesByGroup({ idPlan, idGroup }));
      const data = payload || [];
      setCourses(data);
      if (data.length > 0) setValue('coursesSelect', data[0].idCoursePlan);
    })();
  }, [idPlan]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (watchCourse)
      (async () => {
        const { payload } = await getSemesters();
        const data = payload || [];
        setSemesters(data);
        if (data.length > 0) setValue('semestersSelect', data[0].name.split(' ')[1]);
      })();
  }, [watchCourse]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (watchSemester)
      (async () => {
        const { payload } = await getFormControl();
        const data = payload?.data || [];
        setFormControl(data);
        resetField('controlsSelect');
        if (data.length > 0) setValue('controlsSelect', data[0].id);
      })();
  }, [watchSemester]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (watchControl) getPlan();
  }, [watchControl]);
```

Без понятия на сколько это правильно, но оно работает.